# How to get a number value within an object that is in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

My code:

```
 rbx.getPlayers(539310, 1).promise.then(players => {
  console.log(players)
  for (var list in players.players) {
    console.log(list)
    var key = Object.Key(list)
    console.log(Key)
  }
})
```

What it outputs:

```
{ total: 9,
 players:
         { AgentJay400: 65910635,
           MatthewHAndreas: 49787909,
           coolguysocoolroblox: 165524669,
           CAMPER5155: 45422370,
           Mavnkei: 69082588,
           kaankerem123: 92305180,
           egehan432: 120777218,
           panpanaber54: 31962303,
           IXTactical_CactusXI: 17451343 } }
AgentJay400
MatthewHAndreas
coolguysocoolroblox
CAMPER5155
Mavnkei
kaankerem123
egehan432
panpanaber54
IXTactical_CactusXI
```

Problem: 
I need the number values of each user (So {AgentJay4000: 65910635} I would want the 65910635) Node.js does not seem to have Object.keys so... I have no clue how to get the number...

Comment: Think you've got a typo - `var key = Object.keys(list)` not `var key = Object.Key(list)`

Comment: Also prob not appropriate to use there as list will = a player key and you'd be attempting to run `Object.keys` on a string. `Object.keys(players.players)` will give you an array of keys for all players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node should definitely have `Object.keys`. If your version doesn't you should update node. When you call `Object.keys` you get an array in return, so you can do awesome array things like map, reduce, forEach:

```
Object.keys(players.players).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key, players.players[key])
})
```

If you just want the number values, then map it:

```
Object.keys(players.players).map(function(key) {
  return players.players[key]
})
```

Now you have an array of the numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.You can access your object value using `.` operator.

Suppose you have an object:

```
    var obj={
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2
       }
```

Then access values like `obj.key1` or `obj['key1']`.

to get all the values.Use `Object.values(obj);`

```js
   var obj = { total: 9,
 players:
     { AgentJay400: 65910635,
       MatthewHAndreas: 49787909,
       coolguysocoolroblox: 165524669,
       CAMPER5155: 45422370,
       Mavnkei: 69082588,
       kaankerem123: 92305180,
       egehan432: 120777218,
       panpanaber54: 31962303,
       IXTactical_CactusXI: 17451343 } };
       
       var players  = obj.players;
       var number_values = Object.values(players);
      
       console.log(number_values );
```

Comment: The only problem with that is the object returned will NOT always have the same people.... It gets the names/values based on if they meet a requirement. @Hikmat Sijapati

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: I have all that sorted out, I just need to get the number values from the object.

Comment: All I need is within the for var list in players.players to return the numbers not the strings...

Comment: @ICostaEx Designs in which format you want numbers.Above answer is in  array of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the keys and their associated numbers by doing the following:

```
 rbx.getPlayers(539310, 1).promise.then(players => {
      console.log(players)
      for (var key in players.players) { 
        console.log(key, ':', players.players[key])
      }
 })
```

To demonstrate how `Object.keys` works an alternative method of accessing the players - this does the same as the above.

```
 rbx.getPlayers(539310, 1).promise.then(players => {
      var keys = Object.keys(players.players);

      for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            let key  = keys[i];
            let player = players.players[key];
            console.log(key, ':', players.players[key])
        }

    });
```

The mistakes you made in your attempt were you were attempting to access `Object.key` which was a typo for `Object.keys` and attempting to obtain a list of keys from a string (as a loop such as `for(var key in obj)` will set key to each key in obj and all object keys are strings).